# Screen positions of GUI elements in Unity3D

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine

I am using the standard GUI of Unity3D.

How can I get the screen position of a GUI element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically you can't. Using better words, as you already noticed `GUI.Button` simply returns a bool that indicated if the button has been pressed.

Since you are actually re-creating the button every frame (your `GUI.Button` code is inside a callback such as `Update`,`FixedUpdate`, `OnGUI`,...), and when you are calling `GUI.Button` you are passing it the `Rect` bounds by your self, there isn't actually any need of querying any object to retrieve the actual coordinates. Simply store them somewhere.

```
Rect buttonBounds = new Rect (50,60,100,20);

bool buttonPressed = GUI.Button (buttonBounds, "get postion");

if (buttonPressed)
{
  //you know the bounds, because buttonBounds button has been pressed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var positionGui : Vector2;
positionGui = Vector2 (guiElement.transform.position.x * Screen.width, guiElement.transform.position.y * Screen.height);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

```
public static Rect screenRect
    (float tx,
     float ty,
     float tw,
     float th) 
{
    float x1 = tx * Screen.width;
    float y1 = ty * Screen.height;     
    float sw = tw * Screen.width;
    float sh = th * Screen.height;
    return new Rect(x1,y1,sw,sh);
}
public void OnGUI()
{   


  if (GUI.Button(screenRect(0.4f, 0.6f, 0.2f, 0.1f), "TRY AGAIN")) 

 {  
  Application.LoadLevel(0);

 }

print ("button position + framesize"+screenRect(0.4f, 0.6f, 0.2f, 0.1f));

}
```